# How do I allow my coworker to view the angular app that is hosted on localhost:4200

Tags: angular, localhost

We are connected to the same wi-fi, but when he types localhost:4200 in his browser, he gets the message `Website cannot be found`.

On my computer, I use `npm install ng serve` then it tells me that the app is hosted on localhost:4200 and it works only on my computer.

I have used `ng serve -host 0.0.0.0` and that did not work either.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `--host 0.0.0.0` and the network IP address  in the browser should work (e.g. 10.x.x.x.:4200). Check if your colleague can ping your machine for a start

Comment: tried --host 0.0.0.0 not working.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find your machine lan ip. Use this link https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/wiki/LIS/Step-by-Step:_Finding_the_IP_Address_and_MAC/Physical_Address/Ethernet_ID

And `ng serve --host yourlocalip:4200`

then you can access anywhere from your lan.

Comment: i am getting an error, getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.1.xx.x:4200  ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.1.xx.x:4200 at errnoException (dns.js:50:10) at GetAddrInforReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js92:26)

Comment: your local ip will not start with 10.1. Check again it will be starting with 198.

Comment: I really appreciate you responding quick, thank you! i do not see any thing starting with 198. but i do have IPv4 Address...... 192.xxx.xxx.x i tried it with that as well but am getting the same error message

Comment: yes exactly the one starting with 192. is your machine local ip. 

once you run `ng serve --host 192.x.x.x:4200`

you need to access `192.x.x.x:4200` from your coworker machine.

Comment: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 192.xxx.xxx.x:4200 at errnoException(dns.js:50:10) at GetAddrInforReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)    <-- that is the error i am getting after i run ng serve --host 192.xxx.xxx.x:4200

Comment: Try changing the PORT no to something else